# Почему правки в CSS файле не применяются?

Tags: веб-программирование

когда до этого вносил правки в CSS файл - все применялось. Но теперь они перестали применяться. К примеру: я изменил их и они применяются только через несколько часов. Никак не могу понять - в чем ошибка.Вот код:

```
<?php
    require 'db.php';
    $data = $_POST;
    $errors = array();

    if (isset($data['do_login'])) {
        $user = R::findOne('users', 'user_name = ?', array($data['user_name']));
        if ($user AND trim($data['user_name']) != "") {
            if (password_verify($data['password'], $user->password)) {
                $_SESSION['logged_user'] = $user;
                header('Location: index.php');
        } else {
            $errors[] = 'Пароль введен не верно!';
        }
        } else {
            $errors[] = 'Имя пользователя введено не верно!';
        }

    }
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Авторизация</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="media/login.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="form">
        <img src="media/img/LOGOblue.png" alt="Логотип" id="logo">
        <h1>Авторизоваться</h1>
        <form action="login.php" method="POST">
            <input type="text" class="name" name="user_name" placeholder="Имя пользователя" value="<?php echo @$data['user_name'] ?>"><br>
            <input type="password" class="password" name="password" placeholder="Пароль" value="<?php echo @$data['password'] ?>"><br>
            <input type="submit" value="Войти" class="submit" id="sabmit" name="do_login"><br>
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
<?php
    if (!empty($errors)) {
        echo '<div style="color: #fff; background-color: red; padding: 10px; font-family: Arial; width: 270px; text-align: center; margin-left: 40.5%; margin-top: 5px;">' . array_shift($errors) . '</div>';
    }
?>
```

В чем дело?Помогите пожалуйста.

Comment: В кэше браузера, который вы забываете чистить?

Comment: Почистил кэш, все работает. Сам бы никогда не подумал. Спасибо большое